# Extension Upgrade Failed: Download failed - ZIP file is unavailable or malformed

Tags: wordpress, extension

I'm using CiviCRM 5.0.0 and WordPress 4.9.5, I have CiviRules 1.19 and I have notice that Version 1.21 is available. So I click to update but it has error like picture: 
**Extension Upgrade Failed
Download failed - ZIP file is unavailable or malformed**

[image]

Please help me how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a manual upgrade:

1. download the zipfile from https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules
2. remove the civirules directory from your extension folder on the server
3. extract the downloaded zip file
4. upload the org.civicoop.civirules folder to your extension folder on the server
5. Go to the extension page in civicrm and see whether any database upgrades are reuired.

ps. It is a good habit to make a backup before step 1.

Comment: will the extension need a rename eg from xxx-master to xxx?

Comment: That is not necessarily but I prefer to do it.

Comment: This answer is more a workaround than the solution to the problem.